# datastore and index.yaml: no matching index found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i have a soap service that execute a query on datastore:

```
private final String KEY_NAME = "keyName";
private final String KEY_TYPE = "storedData";
private final String ENTITY_TYPE = "record";
private final String TEMP_ROW = "temperatura";
private final String HUM_ROW = "umidita";
private final String DATE_ROW = "date";
private DatastoreService dataStore;
private Key dataKey = KeyFactory.createKey(KEY_TYPE, KEY_NAME);
private final Query query = new Query(ENTITY_TYPE, dataKey).addSort(DATE_ROW,
    Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING);

@WebMethod
public int sendData(String temperatura, String umidita) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    Entity record = new Entity(ENTITY_TYPE, dataKey);
    record.setProperty(TEMP_ROW, temperatura);
    record.setProperty(HUM_ROW, umidita);
    record.setProperty(DATE_ROW, date);
    dataStore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    dataStore.put(record);  
    return 1;
}
```

and i've write this index.yaml

```
indexes:
- kind: Record
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
      - name: temperatura
      - name: umidita
      - name: data
      direction: asc
```

but when i try to execute that query i have this error:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
<datastore-index kind="Record" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="date" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

what's wrong on index.yaml that doesn't match query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index that you defined are using 3 properties. Your query only use one index, either you changed your query to use 3 properties defined in the index, or you define the date field to be indexed in the model declaration.